# Java Debugging over 2 machines

Tags: java, debugging, remote-desktop

I am working in Linux environment where my java process is running on Machine C.
in order to connect to Machine C from my machine A i need to connect through B for security reason and there is no option to connect directly to machine C.

is there any way to debug the java process that running on machine C.?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to set up port forwarding on machine B.

Comment: Connect to B, and from there, connect to C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up a tunnel through machine B. You can use ssh tunneling by issuing this command from machineA:

```
ssh root@machineB -L 5005:machineC:5005
```

You will need to configure your IDE to debug remotely, pointed at machineA port 5005, and configure the remote JVM on machineC for remote debugging on port 5005, something like this:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

Assuming your IDE is running on the same machine as the ssh client, that is, machineA, you can point your IDE to localhost:5005 and the ssh command will attempt to tunnel all connections you make to localhost:5005 through to machineC:5005.

Comment: Do i need to set the tunneling from machine B , how can i do it?
Thanks

Comment: do i need to do it under:(/etc/ssh/sshd_config or /etc/openssh/sshd_config

Comment: The ssh command creates the tunnel, but I need to edit the answer, because it's incorrect about where you point your IDE debugging session. The `-L` option listens *locally*, that is, on machineA, not on machineB as I stated. My apologies.